# AutoMapper ignore NULL values

Tags: automapper

There seems to be lots of confusion regarding how to achieve this in latest update AutoMapper. I'm using AutoMapper 5.2.0 and the old solutions found on Github Issues and SO are not working.

My requirement is to ignore the mapping if source value is null or empty (for strings) or 0 (for int)

Answer (score 2):

Try using this extension for checking if null:

```
public static void MapFromIfNotNull<TSource, TDestination, TProperty>(
        this IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDestination, TProperty> map, 
        Expression<Func<TSource, object>> selector)
        {
            var function = selector.Compile();
            map.Condition(source => function(source) != null);
            map.MapFrom(selector);
        }
```

Then use

```
CreateMap<EmployeeDTO, Employee>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.MOBILE, opts => opts.MapFromIfNotNull(src => src.MobilePhone))
```